# Receive scheduled downtime notification programmatically for Azure Web App and Cloud Services?

Tags: monitoring, azure, cloud

Can I hook to Azure somehow programmatically to receive scheduled downtime notifications so that we can prepare and notify our clients before hand?

From [Azure SLA for Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/cloud-services/v1_1/) and [Azure SLA for App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_3/) they both say Scheduled Downtime will be notified "at least five (5) days prior to the commencement of such Downtime". But there is no mention of how? Through email or notifications in Azure Portal? So far I have never seen such notifications for my Web App at all. However, I assume there should be system updates going sometime.

It would be handy if I could subscribe to those notifications programmatically or even being able to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Downtime notifications usually relate to VM's, if your purely using App services then you likely won't have seen any, as they are able to migrate app services and keep them up whilst updating, not the same with VM's.

For notifications, they are usually supplied via email, as well as a notification in the portal, although portal notifications I have seen are bit hit and miss sometimes.